# Eclipse : Android SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, message

recently I have downloaded a plug in for Android in Eclipse, but I removed it, because I realized I did not need it. And now it shows me this messages, whenever I start Eclipse..

Console:
[2017-02-25 16:17:56 - SDK Manager] Missing %s file in Android SDK.
[2017-02-25 16:17:56 - SDK Manager] android.bat

Window: 
SDK Platform Tools are missing! Please use the SDK manager to install it.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You fix this problem by installing Android Studio. Google no longer supports Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

That might mean that your sdk downloads are not enough. And you need to update set of sdks.  Try with cleaning the project for the plugin you removed. 
And by the way you should go with Android Studio for Android app development instead eclipse. You will not regret it.